# Как развернуть GitLab runner с Docker executor, используя DebOps?

Tags: docker, gitlab, ansible, gitlab-runner

Хочу развернуть [GitLab runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) с [Docker Executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), используя роли и скрипты от [DebOps](https://docs.debops.org/en/latest/index.html). Документация говорит, что [Docker executor поддерживается](https://docs.debops.org/en/latest/ansible/roles/ansible-gitlab_runner/docs/introduction.html). Пока что у меня получается только Shell executor. Ниже подробности.

Проект инициализировал с помощью `debops-init`. Из документации я сделал вывод, что я должен сам включить роль для Docker:

> To use different executors like SSH or Docker, you need to provide additional configuration and **ensure that required software (ssh, Docker, Docker Machine, etc.) is installed** if required.

Получились такие конфиги:

**ansible/inventory/hosts**:

```ini
[debops_all_hosts]
myhost.domain.tdl ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.11

# чтобы был докер
[debops_service_docker]
myhost.domain.tdl

[debops_service_gitlab_runner]
myhost.domain.tdl
```

**ansible/inventory/group_vars/all/all.yml**:

```python
gitlab_runner__api_url: 'http://gitlab.domain.tld/ci'
gitlab_runner__executor: 'docker'
```

Выполнил следующее:

```
# настройка авторизации
debops bootstrap -u root --ask-pass
# базовая конфигурация и докер
debops

# потом раскомментировал в инвентаре [debops_service_gitlab_runner]
GITLAB_RUNNER_TOKEN=mytokenhere debops service/gitlab_runner
```

В результате в GitLab появился подключенный раннер с Shell executor. Он работает, в логах сборки вижу "Using Shell executor...".

Но я-то хочу Docker executor. Как его получить? Возможные причины:

- Не установил какую-то из нужных зависимостей. Это вообще странно с ansible и DebOps, где все зависимости обычно разрешаются автоматически.
- Неверные значения или не хватает [каких-то переменных](https://docs.debops.org/en/latest/ansible/roles/ansible-gitlab_runner/docs/defaults.html#envvar-gitlab_runner__executor).

---

UPD: посмотрел в конфиги на хосте.
В **/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml** вижу следующее:

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "myhost.domain.tdl"
  url = "http://gitlab.domain.tld/ci"
  token = "mytokenhere"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "debian"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    cap_drop = [ "NET_ADMIN", "SYS_ADMIN", "DAC_OVERRIDE" ]
```

Почему `executor = "shell"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В роли есть такие переменные:

> List of default GitLab Runner instances.

```
gitlab_runner__default_instances: [ '{{ gitlab_runner__instance_shell }}' ]
```

> The default GitLab Runner instance.

```
gitlab_runner__instance_shell:
  name: '{{ gitlab_runner__fqdn }}'
  executor: 'shell'
```

Роль уcтроена таким образом, что `gitlab_runner__executor` имеет значение только, если не указан `executor` у конкретного `runner`'а.

Список `runner`'ов для конфига берется так:

```
for runner in (gitlab_runner__default_instances + gitlab_runner__instances + gitlab_runner__group_instances + gitlab_runner__host_instances)
```

Т.е. чтобы добиться эффекта, нужно, к примеру, переопределить:

```
gitlab_runner__default_instances:
  - name: '{{ gitlab_runner__fqdn }}'
```

и не указывать `executor` и тогда будет использован `gitlab_runner__executor`, либо явно указать:

```
gitlab_runner__default_instances:
  - name: '{{ gitlab_runner__fqdn }}'
    executor: docker
```

*P.S. я это не тестировал – ответ написал, глядя в документацию и код.*

Comment: Добавил такой конфиг, применил, перезапустил конвейер (pipeline). Он остановился на "Pending", в логе пусто, дальше не движется. В `/var/log/syslog` вижу повторяющиеся сообщения про несоответствие версий: `GitLab Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab CE/EE >= 9.0`. Вероятно, про это уже новый вопрос нужно задавать.

Comment: Если `config.toml` похож на ожидаемый, то, вероятно, это уже другая проблема.

Comment: Повторил деплой с нуля, в конфиге вижу только одну строку: `concurrent = 1`. То есть воспроизводимого результата так и нет, теперь он вообще не регистрируется.

Comment: Попробуй добавить докер-раннер в `gitlab_runner__instances`.

Comment: Обнаружил проблему: я на автомате поправил http на https, который не настроен на гитлабе. Соответственно, он не обнаруживался, раннер не регистрировался. Так что этот шаг пройден, спасибо.