# Ошибка "Error reading remote info: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type bool"

Tags: docker, gitlab-runner

Развернул GitLab Runner с Docker executor ([подробности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676689/181472)).

Запускаю простейший конвейер:

```
image: alpine

test:
  script:
  - echo 'Hello world'
```

Он проваливается, лог такой:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.2.0 (adfc387)
  on myhost.domain.tdl (44a313eb)
Using Docker executor with image alpine ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error reading remote info: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type bool
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image alpine ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error reading remote info: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type bool
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image alpine ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error reading remote info: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type bool
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error reading remote info: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type bool
```

Что не так? Выглядит как исключение откуда-то из недр Go. Неясно даже, как дебажить.

---

#### Конфиг:

```
$ cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml 
# This file is managed remotely, all changes will be lost

concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "myhost.domain.tdl"
  url = "http://gitlab.domain.tld/ci"
  token = "mytokenhere"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "debian"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    cap_drop = [ "NET_ADMIN", "SYS_ADMIN", "DAC_OVERRIDE" ]
```

#### Docker:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
$ docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 997.1 MiB
Name: db80x64-vm
ID: FZ72:HSJJ:CE4G:WCTI:O2JC:7VQM:T5IL:KXHJ:4TK2:U2S7:G4QV:5C4X
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия Docker очень старая, необходимо обновить.

Вот обсуждения этой проблемы: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2271

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо. Решил задачу тем, что разрешил upstream в роли debops.docker: `docker__upstream: True`. Не возражаете, если дополню ответ?

Comment: Да, пожалуйста.