# Ошибка "'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host"

Tags: linux, debian, docker

Debian 8, установил докер, не могу запустить. Устанавливал ролью [debops/ansible-docker](https://github.com/debops/ansible-docker), роль завершилась с ошибкой рестарта сервиса:

```
$ systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

#### OS

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie
```

#### systemctl status docker.service

```
$  systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─http-proxy.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-06-08 10:35:27 +07; 3min 16s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 9896 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9896 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: time="2017-06-08T10:35:27.219755757+07:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 9901"
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: time="2017-06-08T10:35:27.233172412+07:00" level=warning msg="failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: %!s(<nil>). Deleting synchronously"
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: time="2017-06-08T10:35:27.235146761+07:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded."
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Вызывает особые подозрения эта строка:

> 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.

#### journalctl -xn

```
$ journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Wed 2017-06-07 15:14:31 +07, end at Thu 2017-06-08 10:39:14 +07. --
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: time="2017-06-08T10:35:27.235146761+07:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded."
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname dockerd[9896]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 08 10:35:27 myhostname systemd[1]: Unit docker.socket entered failed state.
Jun 08 10:39:14 myhostname ntpd[4693]: peer 2a00:ab00:300:657::1000:6 now invalid
```

Пробовал сменить используемый драйвер на aufs по рецепту из [Docker service does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132706/docker-service-does-not-start), результат остался тем же.

Судя по другому ответу там же, дело может быть в том, что конкретная версия ядра не поддерживает overlay. Поменять используемый образ ОС будет сложно. Есть ли другие варианты, например установить overlay или как-либо обойти проблему?

Comment: В итоге обошел проблему тем, что использовал образ Ubuntu 16.04 вместо Debian 8. Но это не решение. Ответ с решением для Debian 8 по-прежнему нужен и интересен.

Comment: откуда устанавливали? я такой версии среди стабильных сборок не наблюдаю: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/jessie/pool/stable/amd64/ тем более среди того, что *на самом деле* должно работать: https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/docker.io

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот подробности установки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676767/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-error-reading-remote-info-json-cannot-unmarshal-number-into-go-value-o#comment988815_676779

Comment: увы, так и не понял, откуда у вас взялась программа docker. в общем — пишите туда, откуда её скачали, мол, не работает этот блоб в той версии дистрибутива, для которой вы его собирали. но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы ставили не ту версию, которая собиралась именно для jessie.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin docker установлен и настроен ролью debops/ansible-docker, ссылка в самом начале вопроса есть. Почти наверняка использовался [вот такой репозиторий](https://github.com/debops/ansible-docker/blob/64b1ea1b7f0507544815f2cd6410bac3b2fd1e11/defaults/main.yml#L53), дефолтное значение переменной я не менял.

Comment: уточните, входит ли запускаемая программа *docker* в какой-нибудь пакет, определите его версию, и сравните с теми, что прописаны в упомянутом репозитории: `$ curl -s https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/debian-jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep -i ^version`. если сходится, то багрепорт надо писать в этот dockerproject.org, если не сходится, то разбираться дальше. // кстати, там в репозитории мноно версий собрано. вы можете повлиять на номер устанавливаемой версии пакета?

Comment: Я плаваю в этой теме, но вроде как всегда можно использовать devicemapper, который должен быть доступен во всех ядрах

Comment: @alexanderbarakin убунтой. А на дебиане так и не завел докер. Пробовал и аптгетом ставить, то же самое.

Comment: честно говоря, не понял юмора: пакет и в вопросе ставится с помощью программы apt-get. только в вопросе пакет явно поломанный. [ставьте работоспособный](https://wiki.debian.org/Docker).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin однако, на убунте та же версия: `# docker --version`
`Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`. Выходит, что не в ней дело. Я понимаю, что выглядит странно — но вот как есть. Версию пакета по вашей инструкции пока что не определял.

Comment: понятно, что дело в версии программы linux (и в наборе собранных для неё модулей). тот пакет, что устанавливается в вопросе, судя по информации из вопроса, собран явно не для jessie и входящей в этот выпуск версии программы linux. // абсолютно ничего странного — надо всего лишь ставить пакет с заведемо работоспособной (с данной версией программы linux) сборкой программы docker.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага, теперь яснее. Попробую запустить ansible с `-vvvv` и/или вывести в консоль полученное значение репозитория. Возможно, не тот репозиторий был использован.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот для убунты получился `deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main"`.